# gcc4.7 error - dereferencing type-punned pointer

Tags: c, gcc4

I have a third-party piece of code to compile, below is the snippet that fails:

```
typedef struct wqe_s {
   ...
   uint8_t packet_data[96]
   ...
} wqe_t;

..
wqe_t *work = NULL;
..
wqe_t *w1 = *(wqe_t **)work->packet_data;  // ERROR
```

> error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing
>   rules

It is compiled with gcc-4.7 (-Wall -Werror), I don't think I need to adjust compiler flags, the best would be to fix the code.

I would appreciate to get some advice for this. Thanks!

Comment: This code and the right solution below still have the portability problem of endianness. May be in the real program it is taken care of but this excerpt does not.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
wqe_t *w1;
memcpy(&w1, work->packet_data, sizeof w1);
```

Comment: @Kerrek DB, thanks for response. I'm not sure I'm following your suggestion -- you copy [sizeof w1] bytes of memory from area pointed by work->packet_data to where pointer w1 is located, i.e. on the stack, however in the original code (which gcc isn't happy about) they copy pointers. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mark: The original code pretends that an area of memory is an object of a certain type `T` (which is the illegal type punning) by treating the pointer to the memory as a pointer-to-`T` and dereferencing that. My code creates an actual object of type `T` (so there is now such an object) and then copies data into its underlying representation. (Here `T = wqe_t*`.)